# access denied in mysql

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm new to mySql and having a lot of trouble just getting a downloaded sql file into a database. I'm working off of the command line in the most current version of raspbian on my raspberry pi.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON bbdatabank.* TO 'pi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE bbdatabank;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
```

When I try to link my sql file (lahman2012.sql) to the database I get an error even though I use the password above (password)

```
mysql -u pi -p -s bbdatabank < lahman2012.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost' to database 'bbdatabank'
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to reload the user table within MySQL:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html

Comment: Not necessary unless you modify the privilege tables directly (which isn't happening here). `GRANT`s always take effect immediately.

Comment: @duskwuff: Normally yes, but there have been a few bugs with this behaviour, for example: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62390

Comment: I tried it after re-entering the above code and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

my personal suggestion is try to make the sql user with the wildcard

something like

```
CREATE USER 'pi'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xyz';
```

that ways if there are any discrepancies it would overlook it

Comment: would I enter the above code instead of something I had or in addition?